# How could I do login of a user during registration form process

Tags: plone

A customer ask to create a one step form : registration + login;

I have configure plone to let the user choose the password, so at data level we should be able to achieve this.

Now at code level, I have no idea which API I'm supposed to use to 'logged in' a user while having it's username and password.

By default Plone show two screen after the registration before having the web site:

- registration form
- success page with a login button
- success logged in page.
- have to move your self in the website has member

I want to short cut this to:

- registration form
- redirect to dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `updateCredentials()` method on the `acl_users` user folder; it'll call the right plugins, resulting in a cookie being set for the user in a default Plone setup:

```
users = getToolByName(self.context, 'acl_users')
users.updateCredentials(self.request, self.request.response, username, password)
```

The method needs request, response, username and password parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Customize portal_skins/plone_login/registered and insert a redirect to the dashboard.